# Query to find accounts with specified months

Tags: sql

I Want to extract those account ids which are present in may and JUNE but not in JULY . I have data for 6 months

i have tried using CONDITION(AND/ NOT)

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID, DATA_MONTH
FROM DATA1
WHERE DATA_MONTH ='01-MAY-18' AND DATA_MONTH <> '01-JULY-18
GROUP BY DATA_MONTH
```

I am still getting account ids which where in JULY

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Column DATA_MONTH data type?

Comment: Do you mean _both_ May **and** June, or is just one of them fine? Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example before you start.

Comment: Yes  i would want both may and june but not july

Comment: Please note that typing in ALL CAPS is considered rude and seen as yelling.

Comment: It sounds like you need to do relational division. There is a great article on this here: [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date formats look like Oracle, so I will answer for that database.

The idea is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID, DATA_MONTH
FROM DATA1
WHERE DATA_MONTH >= DATE '2018-05-01' AND
      DATA_MONTH < DATE '2018-08-01'
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATA_MONTH) = 2 AND
       MAX(DATA_MONTH) < DATE '2018-07-01';
```

This assumes that all your dates are on the first of the month.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the conditions you need in a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
FROM DATA1
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID
HAVING
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DATA_MONTH) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
  AND
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DATA_MONTH) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
  AND
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DATA_MONTH) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

I assume that in your rdbms there exists a function like `MONTH()` to extract the month from the date. 
If you want to check the year also, you can do it in each condition, so you must change to:

```
CASE WHEN MONTH(DATA_MONTH) = 7 AND YEAR(DATA_MONTH) = 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server's Month function gives you an understandable example of how to solve this.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
FROM DATA1
WHERE MONTH(DATA_MONTH) in (5,6) AND YEAR(DATA_MONTH) = 2018 AND MONTH(DATA_MONTH) NOT IN (7) 
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID
```

Comment: Seems like you missed the "_but not in JULY_" part.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID, DATA_MONTH
FROM DATA1
WHERE MONTH(DATA_MONTH) =5 AND MONTH(DATA_MONTH) = 6
GROUP BY DATA_MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID, DATA_MONTH
FROM DATA1
WHERE MONTH(DATA_MONTH)  BETWEEN 5  AND  6
GROUP BY Year(DATA_MONTH),month(DATA_MONTH)
```